# AMQP Golang priority not working

Tags: go, rabbitmq

I am currently testing rabbitmq with golang (github.com/streadway/amqp), and I have three programs, two of them sending messages to the queue with different priorities and one reading from the queue.
And the problem I am having is that after sending a few messages with the two programs I then proceed to launch the program that will read from the queue and when it starts to read from the queue it output the result like a FIFO.
I expected to output the high priority first followed by the lower priority message.
Did I misunderstand how rabbitmq works or am I doing something wrong?

Sending to queues
    package main

```
import (
        "log"

        "github.com/streadway/amqp"
)

func failOnError(err error, msg string) {
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("%s: %s", msg, err)
        }
}

func main() {
        args := make(amqp.Table)
        args["x-max-priority"] = int64(9)

        conn, err := amqp.Dial("amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/")
        failOnError(err, "Failed to connect to RabbitMQ")
        defer conn.Close()

        ch, err := conn.Channel()
        failOnError(err, "Failed to open a channel")
        defer ch.Close()

        q, err := ch.QueueDeclare(
                "test", // name                                                                                                                                                                                     
                false,   // durable                                                                                                                                                                                 
                false,   // delete when unused                                                                                                                                                                      
                false,   // exclusive                                                                                                                                                                               
                false,   // no-wait                                                                                                                                                                                 
                args,     // arguments                                                                                                                                                                              
        )
        failOnError(err, "Failed to declare a queue")

        body := "low"
        err = ch.Publish(
                "",     // exchange                                                                                                                                                                                 
                q.Name, // routing key                                                                                                                                                                              
                false,  // mandatory                                                                                                                                                                                
                false,  // immediate                                                                                                                                                                                
                amqp.Publishing{
                        Headers:         amqp.Table{},
                        ContentType:     "text/plain",
                        ContentEncoding: "",
                        Body:            []byte(body),
                        DeliveryMode:    amqp.Transient, // 1=non-persistent, 2=persistent                                                                                                                          
                        Priority: 0,
                })
        log.Printf(" [x] Sent %s", body)
        failOnError(err, "Failed to publish a message")

        body = "low"
        err = ch.Publish(
                "",     // exchange                                                                                                                                                                                 
                q.Name, // routing key                                                                                                                                                                              
                false,  // mandatory                                                                                                                                                                                
                false,  // immediate                                                                                                                                                                                
                amqp.Publishing{
                        Headers:         amqp.Table{},
                        ContentType:     "text/plain",
                        ContentEncoding: "",
                        Body:            []byte(body),
                        DeliveryMode:    amqp.Transient, // 1=non-persistent, 2=persistent                                                                                                                          
                        Priority: 0,
                })
        log.Printf(" [x] Sent %s", body)
        failOnError(err, "Failed to publish a message")

        body = "low"
        err = ch.Publish(
                "",     // exchange                                                                                                                                                                                 
                q.Name, // routing key                                                                                                                                                                              
                false,  // mandatory                                                                                                                                                                                
                false,  // immediate                                                                                                                                                                                
                amqp.Publishing{
                        Headers:         amqp.Table{},
                        ContentType:     "text/plain",
                        ContentEncoding: "",
                        Body:            []byte(body),
                        DeliveryMode:    amqp.Transient, // 1=non-persistent, 2=persistent                                                                                                                          
                        Priority: 0,
                })
        log.Printf(" [x] Sent %s", body)
        failOnError(err, "Failed to publish a message")


        body = "high"
        err = ch.Publish(
                "",     // exchange                                                                                                                                                                                 
                q.Name, // routing key                                                                                                                                                                              
                false,  // mandatory                                                                                                                                                                                
                false,  // immediate                                                                                                                                                                                
                amqp.Publishing{
                        Headers:         amqp.Table{},
                        ContentType:     "text/plain",
                        ContentEncoding: "",
                        Body:            []byte(body),
                        DeliveryMode:    amqp.Transient, // 1=non-persistent, 2=persistent                                                                                                                          
                        Priority: 9,
                })
        log.Printf(" [x] Sent %s", body)
        failOnError(err, "Failed to publish a message")


        body = "low"
        err = ch.Publish(
                "",     // exchange                                                                                                                                                                                 
                q.Name, // routing key                                                                                                                                                                              
                false,  // mandatory                                                                                                                                                                                
                false,  // immediate                                                                                                                                                                                
                amqp.Publishing{
                        Headers:         amqp.Table{},
                        ContentType:     "text/plain",
                        ContentEncoding: "",
                        Body:            []byte(body),
                        DeliveryMode:    amqp.Transient, // 1=non-persistent, 2=persistent                                                                                                                          
                        Priority: 0,
                })
        log.Printf(" [x] Sent %s", body)
        failOnError(err, "Failed to publish a message")


        body = "low"
        err = ch.Publish(
                "",     // exchange                                                                                                                                                                                 
                q.Name, // routing key                                                                                                                                                                              
                false,  // mandatory                                                                                                                                                                                
                false,  // immediate                                                                                                                                                                                
                amqp.Publishing{
                        Headers:         amqp.Table{},
                        ContentType:     "text/plain",
                        ContentEncoding: "",
                        Body:            []byte(body),
                        DeliveryMode:    amqp.Transient, // 1=non-persistent, 2=persistent                                                                                                                          
                        Priority: 0,
                })
        log.Printf(" [x] Sent %s", body)
        failOnError(err, "Failed to publish a message")


        body = "low"
        err = ch.Publish(
                "",     // exchange                                                                                                                                                                                 
                q.Name, // routing key                                                                                                                                                                              
                false,  // mandatory                                                                                                                                                                                
                false,  // immediate                                                                                                                                                                                
                amqp.Publishing{
                        Headers:         amqp.Table{},
                        ContentType:     "text/plain",
                        ContentEncoding: "",
                        Body:            []byte(body),
                        DeliveryMode:    amqp.Transient, // 1=non-persistent, 2=persistent                                                                                                                          
                        Priority: 0,
                })
        log.Printf(" [x] Sent %s", body)
        failOnError(err, "Failed to publish a message")

}
```

Reading queue:

```
package main

import (
        "log"

        "github.com/streadway/amqp"
)

func failOnError(err error, msg string) {
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("%s: %s", msg, err)
        }
}

func main() {
        args := make(amqp.Table)
        args["x-max-priority"] = int64(9)

        conn, err := amqp.Dial("amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/")
        failOnError(err, "Failed to connect to RabbitMQ")

        ch, err := conn.Channel()
        failOnError(err, "Failed to open a channel")

        q, err := ch.QueueDeclare(
                "test", // name                                                                                                                                                                                     
                false,   // durable                                                                                                                                                                                 
                false,   // delete when unused                                                                                                                                                                      
                false,   // exclusive                                                                                                                                                                               
                false,   // no-wait                                                                                                                                                                                 
                args,     // arguments                                                                                                                                                                              
        )
        failOnError(err, "Failed to declare a queue")

        msgs, err := ch.Consume(
                q.Name, // queue                                                                                                                                                                                    
                "",     // consumer                                                                                                                                                                                 
                true,   // auto-ack                                                                                                                                                                                 
                false,  // exclusive                                                                                                                                                                                
                false,  // no-local                                                                                                                                                                                 
                false,  // no-wait                                                                                                                                                                                  
                args,    // args                                                                                                                                                                                    
        )
        failOnError(err, "Failed to register a consumer")

        defer ch.Close()
        defer conn.Close()

        forever := make(chan bool)

        go func() {
                for d := range msgs {
                        log.Printf("Received a message: %s", d.Body)
                }
        }()

        log.Printf(" [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C")
        <-forever
}
```

First I launch the code sending the messages to the queue the following values:

- low
- low
- low
- high
- low
- low
- low

With the `low` messages having a priority of 0 and the `high` a priority of 9.
Then I launch the program that will receive the queue.
Expected output:

- high
- low
- low
- low
- low
- low
- low

Actual output:

- low
- low
- low
- high
- low
- low
- low

Thank you

Comment: I believe you want `x-max-priority`, not `x-priority` for your args table.

Comment: I changed the arg to x-max-priority, but alas that did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated to the most recent rabbitmq and it worked, I do not know if this is the only solution.

As well as callign `ch.Qos(1, 0, false)` I also needed to remove the `auto-ack` and acknowledge the message manually afterwards so that it doesn't acknowledge all the messages in the queue.

Comment: Which version did you use prior to the update? as is stated [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/priority.html), priority queue is part of core rabbitmq since 3.5, so if you had been using an older version, you probably would have had to install a module for it to be available

Comment: However, I am now using the func (*Channel) Get instead of the func (*Channel) Consume, because with func (*Channel) Consume it does not seem to sort by priority if I leave it running.

Comment: They do indicate in the documentation that you should leave enough time for the server to sort the queue, had you configured the prefetch in your consumer config?

Comment: `ch.Qos(1, 0, false)` in both the receiver and sender but I still have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

This is what I can figure out from your code, and the description of the steps you follow.

It seems the issue is you do not create the queue the same way in each piece of code, the low and high priority producers create the queue withouth x-max-priority argument.

As a queue is defined as a priority queue upon creation, and only at that time, you actually created a "standard" queue.

You should be able to easily confirm this checking the created queue and its arguments.

Comment: I added x-max-priority to the sending program and even merged both program so that they use the same queue when adding to it, however I still get the same result.

Comment: Did you also delete the queue created during your previous tests?

Comment: I've tried it with a new queue but I still get the same result. Even sometimes I only receive receive the first message from the queue.